# Update a field value of user Submission from FormStack API

Tags: formstack

I am trying to update a field value from No to Yes using FormStack API from this URL:
https://developers.formstack.com/docs/submission-id-put

The description says: **Update the specified submission**

When I update a field using Submission Id let's say 12345 and putting value **field_54321=Yes** in field_x text box, it gives me 200 OK status code but when I check the value in the submissions list from dashboard, the value doesn't get changed.

I also noticed that there is no write permission form submissions in API authorization.

[image: Note that Submissions have no write access]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the method you've described isn't working, but here is a test and a workaround:

1) try using the same API methods/syntax to update your form. For example, if you have a picklist, try updating the options for the picklist. Proving that you are able to correctly use a PUT request to update something in the request rules out syntax problems (or at least narrows it down).

2) You could try using a GET request to get a JSON object of the submission you are trying to update then simply update the desired value and use a POST request to create a new submission. If it works, you have a workaround!

Also, please include your code below so we can diagnose further